# MYSQL >> Index , and .5 sec updates in 4k record table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I got a table that gets updated every half a sec. Multiple columns. The table has 4k rows.
Is it wise to creat indexs and use them when I select ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  Yes.

Not so short answer: Definitely.

Long answer:  Show us the queries (SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE) that you use on that table.  We can make the answer even longer.

But.  Do not simply "index every column".  We will at each query and find the optimal index for it.